# Downloaded images from the Metropolitan Museum collection are empty

Tags: image, python-2.7, api, download, urlrequest

I'm trying to download random public domain images from the Metropolitan Museum collection using their API (more info here : https://metmuseum.github.io/) and Python, unfortunatly the images I get are empty. Here is a minimal code :

```
import urllib
from urllib2 import urlopen
import json
from random import randint

url = "https://collectionapi.metmuseum.org/public/collection/v1/objects"
objectID_list = json.loads(urlopen(url).read())['objectIDs']
objectID = objectID_list[randint(0,len(objectID_list)-1)]
url_request = url+"/"+str(objectID)
fetched_data = json.loads(urlopen(url_request).read())
if fetched_data['isPublicDomain']:
    name = str(fetched_data['title'])
    ID = str(fetched_data['objectID'])
    url_image = str(fetched_data['primaryImage'])
    urllib.urlretrieve(url_image, 'path/'+name+'_'+ID+'.jpg')
```

If I print url_image and copy/paste it in a browser I get to the desired image, but the code retrieves an image that weights 1ko and can't be opened.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your way of downloading is correct, however, it seems as the domain is validating request headers to prevent scraping (probably unintended as they have an API to pull images).

One way of solving this problem is by changing your headers to something realistic, or utilizing [`fake_useragent`](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/) and `requests`.

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

def save_image(link, file_path):
    ua = UserAgent(verify_ssl=False)
    headers = {"User-Agent": ua.random}
    r = requests.get(link, stream=True, headers=headers)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)
    else:
        raise Exception("Error code {}.".format(r.status_code))
```

Comment: Well, it worked for two images and then stopped working. Now the images are 1ko again.